# Precision in Program analysis

Tags: precision, static-analysis

According to David Brumley's Control Flow Integrity & Software Fault Isolation (PPT slide),

in the below statements, x is always 8 due to the path to the x=7 is unrealizable even with the path sensitive analysis.

Why is that?
Is it because the analysis cannot determine the values of n, a, b, and c in advance during the analysis? Or is it because there's no solution that can be calculated by a computer?

---

if(a^n + b^n = c^n && n>2 && a>0 && b>0 && c>0) 
     x = 7;  /*unrealizable path*/
else

### x = 8;

Comment: What does the `^` operator mean in this context?

Comment: It's to the power of n.

Comment: The point seems to be that there is no set of values for a, b, c & n that would satisfy the equation under the given constraints. Is this true? I don't know, but it would be a very odd example to give if it were not - but it seems somewhat esoteric in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the task to determine which path in the program is taken, and which — not, is undecidable. It is quite possible that a particular expression, as in your example, can be proved to have a specific value. However, the words "in general" and "undecidable" say that you cannot write an algorithm that would be able to compute the value every time.

At this point the analysis algorithm can be optimistic or pessimistic. The optimistic one could pick `8` and be fine — it considers possible that at run-time `x` would get this value. It could also pick `7` — "who knows, maybe, `x` would be `7`". But if the analysis is required to be sound, and it cannot determine the value of the condition, it should assume that the first branch could be taken during one execution, and the second branch could be taken during another execution, so `x` could be either `7` or `8`.

In other words, there is a trade-off between soundness and precision. Or, actually, between soundness, precision, and decidability. The latter property tells if the analysis always terminates. Now, you have to pick what is needed:

- Decidability — this is a common choice for compilers and code analyzers, because you would like to get an answer about your program in finite time. However, proof assistants could start some processes that could run up to the specified time limit, and if the limit is not set, forever: it's up to the user to stop it and to try something else.
- Soundness — this is a common choice for compilers, because you would like to get the answer that matches the language specification. Code analyzers are more flexible. Many of them are unsound, but because of that they can find more potential issues in finite time, leaving the interpretation to the developer. I believe the example you mention talks about sound analysis.
- Precision — this is a rare property. Compilers and code analyzer should be pessimistic, because otherwise some incorrect code could sneak in. But this might be parameterizable. E.g., if the compiler/analyzer supports constant propagation and folding, and all of the variables in the example are set to some known constants before the condition, it can figure out the exact value of `x` after it, and be completely precise.